# van Kampen theorem for fundamental groupoid of $X$ relative to $A$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, groupoids

Let $X$ be a manifold with submanifold $A \subseteq X$. Let $\Pi_{1}(X,A)$ denote the homotopy classes of paths with endpoints lying in $A$. This is a Lie groupoid with set of objects $A$. For example, if $X$ is the upper hemisphere of a sphere and $A \cong S^1$ is the equator, then $\Pi_{1}(X,A) \cong S^1$, and for any two objects there is a single morphism.

Question: Is there any theory developed for such groupoids? I'm looking for some kind of van Kampen theorem allowing me to express $\Pi_{1}(X,A)$ in terms of $\Pi_{1}(A)$ and $\Pi_{1}(X \setminus A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure!

There is the book by R. Brown, "Topology and Groupoids", which treats exactly this: http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html

Look also here: http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html

On the nlab (if you didn't know the site, take a look!) there are also these articles that you may find interesting!

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+theorem

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+homotopy+van+Kampen+theorem

Comment: See also my answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39818/the-higher-van-kampen-theorems-and-computation-of-the-unstable-homotopy-groups-o/39868#39868, and presentations on my my preprint page http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/brownpr.html .